# My ham radio is doing some wacky crap

Tags: baofeng, equipment-troubleshooting

Sometimes my Baofeng UV-5R's display will turn red for no apparent reason. I don't know what else to call this so I'll just say phenomena.

I have made sure the antenna is properly connected, and when I lower the squelch all the way down to zero, it works for a while but all I hear is static. Also, sometimes when I have the squelch all the way down, if I press a single button the radio does the phenomena again.

This is *quite* annoying. Also sometimes the language changes but I fixed that a bit ago.

Comment: You clicked on a button that said "ask a question", but you didn't ask a question. So in exchange for your observation I'll make an observaton of my own: if you buy cheap, be prepared to replace it when it breaks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are few ways to know you are even getting a "real" Baofeng, as well. The original units are capable enough, but the market is so full of bad hard to detect clones it can be difficult to know what you have. At any rate, such devices are more computer than radio these days; find out how to completely reset the device and see if that helps.

Comment: nevermind fixed it basically I had to restart it and yeah so it makes me keep writing stuff so yeah

Answer (score 0):

The Baofeng's display color is *programmable*- through an obscure and impossible-to-remember keystroke sequence, you can select from a variety of colors for both transmit and receive.

It surprises me not at all that the Baofeng would self-glitch and shift colors on you randomly. My intent is to replace mine with a Yaesu equivalent, the only problem being that there are so many different Yaesu dual-band handhelds on the used market that I have no idea which one to buy!

Comment: It almost doesn't matter much which Yaesu handheld you get. The classic FT-60 is hard to beat.

Comment: @JonCuster thanks for that, I'll look for one. -NN